# How can I enable html autocomplete in .tmpl files?

Tags: autocompletion, filetype, plugin-coc, filetype-html

I'm editing `.tmpl` files which are mostly html with some template language syntax inside `{{ double curly braces }}`.

I'm using `COC` for autocompletion and I want to be able to use the autocomplete suggestions for `html` but it's not working because it's not a `.html` file.

How can I enable `html` autocompletion in `.tmpl` files? Or how can I tell vim to treat a `.tmpl` file as if it were both a `.tmpl`, and `.html`?

Comment: You can try `:set filetype=tmpl.html` (substitute whatever filetype templates files have for `tmpl`)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble wait. Can I concat _any_ two/more filetypes? How about `cpp.python`?

Comment: @kadekai yes, but be warned (from experience): lots of things like syntax will just end as whatever the last one is. Mappings can override each other, etc. It’s not as good a solution as I want but it’s what we have.